# Copying existing site to LOCALHOST. Tried opening home page, Error: Failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache, xampp

Warning: require(/usr/share/php/wp-stack-cache.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\model\public_html\wp-content\mu-plugins\wp-stack-cache.php on line 31
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/usr/share/php/wp-stack-cache.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\model\public_html\wp-content\mu-plugins\wp-stack-cache.php:31 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\model\public_html\wp-settings.php(322): include_once() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\model\public_html\wp-config.php(82): require_once('C:
xampp
htdocs...') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\model\public_html\wp-load.php(37): require_once('C:
xampp
htdocs...') #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\model\public_html\wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('C:
xampp
htdocs...') #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\model\public_html\index.php(17): require('C:
xampp
htdocs...') #5 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\model\public_html\wp-content\mu-plugins\wp-stack-cache.php on line 31
There has been a critical error on this website.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Looks like you've copied the files from a Linux system to a Windows system without changing the file paths. Windows uses C:\, while Linux starts with `/` as the root directory

Comment: I've downloaded the backup from the host. I  am working in the xampp @aynber. Can you help me out

Comment: You forgot to share the code and your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I see you're trying to copy a WordPress website down to your localhost, I've had to do this from a Linux server not too long ago and found this plugin (https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/) to be super helpful. Install it and export it to a file and then import it and it should clear up the majority of the problems you're having!

Comment: I don't have the working site now. I've backed up this data one month ago. How to install this plugin now?

Comment: you could try using a Linux VM in Windows to get a better environment, if not your going to have to go through the files and change the Linux OS paths to Windows paths